# NSTextfield not accepting keyevents on NSWindow which has NSTitledWindowMask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nstextfield

I have started coding cocoa app. I have created a `NSwindow` with initWithContentRect. 
I have created a `NSTextField`. I can not get any of the keyboard events. It is selectable. I also explicitly set editable to true. 
I have realized there are similar questions but they are mostly about the responder, key window and `Borderlesswindow style`.

I have a `NSWindows` which has a titled window mask , is the key window and it is selected when I set it to be the first responder.

But why cant I type anything into the box.

```
int style = NSClosableWindowMask  |NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask;

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 130, 150)
styleMask:style backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

CGFloat height=20;
NSTextField  * username=[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, NSHeight(window.frame)-80, 100, height)];
[username setEditable:true];
[window.contentView addSubview:username ];
```

Is it because I need to create a subclass of `NSwindow`. I see this is suggested when the style is `NSBorderlessWindowMask`  and by overriding

`canBecomeKeyWindow` it is suggested to solve the issue.

But I am not using `NSBorderlessWindowMask`.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think the window is key? Is this a normally-constructed, bundled app with a `main()` function that calls `NSApplicationMain()`, or are you doing something unusual? Is it a UI element (`LSUIElement` flag in the Info.plist)? Is your app active?

Comment: I recreated the app as a cocaApp. I works now. I did not have a plist in my original version. I think the project started off as a command line tool first.
PS NSwindows has a function called isKeyWindow or something like that. 

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, you say you don't have a Info.plist file. I'm guessing your app isn't even bundled. This is a **crucial** fact that you left out of your question, which only makes it hard for people to help you.

First, you should create apps the normal way. Make a bundled app with a main NIB. Follow the standard template, except delete the window from the main NIB and [use separate window NIBs](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html).

If you aren't equipped to understand what's going wrong with a "manually" constructed app and fix it, then you really shouldn't be going that route.

That said, an unbundled app will start life as a background-only process. What little interactivity you're seeing is, more or less, a bug. You can transform your app into a foreground app by setting the `activationPolicy` of the application object (instance of `NSApplication` or a subclass) to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`. Then, make it the active app by calling `[NSApp activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps]`.